# Struct and Pointers C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, typedef

I am experimenting with Struct, pointers and typedef in the code below. I want to create a pointer to a struct that I made up. Then I want to manipulate the struct's members using the -> operator.

The below code compiles fine, however, when I run the program it produces a segmentation fault.

Can someone please help explain where my logic went wrong?

Thank you.

```
struct Structure1 {
char c;
int i;
float f;
double d;
};

typedef Structure1* structp;

int main(){
structp s1, s2;
s1->c = 'a';
s1->i = 1;
s1->f = 3.14;
s1->d = 0.00093;
s2->c = 'a';
s2->i = 1;
s2->f = 3.14;
s2->d = 0.00093;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
structp s1, s2;
```

You've declared two pointers, `s1` and `s2` but they don't point anywhere yet! You need to allocate memory for these pointers using `new`.

```
s1 = new Structure1();
s1->c = 'a';
s1->i = 1;
// ...
```

Don't forget to delete the memory afterwards:

```
delete s1;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) why the parentheses in `new Structure1()` make a difference. Also, note that there are other ways to obtain a pointer to an object, such as using the `&` operator, but in this particular case, I think you want to allocate memory.

Comment: Do note that the `new` operator is not the only way to get an address of a valid object.  You can also apply the `&` operator to an existing object of the correct type.  Or, in this case of "plain old data", cast any pointer to a memory region which is large enough.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are objects in memory that point to another object. When using the *indirection operator* it causes the pointer to be dereferenced. For example, this:

```
s1->c;
```

is the same as:

```
(*s1).c;
```

When you dereference a pointer, it returns a reference to the object that it points to. If there is no object that it points to (or it points to `nullptr`), deferencing it gives your program [**Undefined Behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The solution would be to create a new instance of a class on the heap and return a pointer to it. That is what **`new`** does:

> ```
> Structure1 *structp = new Structure1();
> ```

It makes sense once you realize that pointers are not the actual objects, they are simply memory addresses. If you don't allocate space or assign to it a memory address, it will remain uninitialized and filled in with garbage. Just like a regular object, why would you want to use an initialized pointer?